# Sticky footer Orchard CMS

Tags: html, css, orchardcms

I am trying to apply a sticky footer but having problems to implement this within Orchard.

In a previous website I have applied the following sticky footer method successfully:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

I just cannot get a sticky footer to work within Orchard, nor can I find anything about it.

Already tried deleting all the existing CSS to attempt to find out why its not working without any success. Not getting any wiser when inspecting the HTML with firebug either.

Template used: Custom theme based Theme Machine (structure wise unchanged).

**Problem:**

The zone padding in `site.css` is giving these odd problems.  But how can i remain the padding from this so i can achieve a sticky footer?

Because without the zone padding all the necessary padding for all the zones is gone.

```
/* Zones */
.zone 
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

*Or is there a other method more suited for Orchard to achieve a sticky footer?*

**Side note question**

*What exactly is the purpose of @tag.StartElement and @tag.EndElement ?*

**CSS:**
(My footer is exactly 40px in height)

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

#layout-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }

#layout-footer 
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px; /* negative value of footer height */
    clear:both;
    background-color: #030e27;
}
```

**Layout.cshmtl:**

```
@tag.StartElement
@if (Model.Header != null) 
{
    <header>
        <div id="layout-header" class="group">
            <div id="header">
                @Zone(Model.Header)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="layout-header-bottom"></div>
    </header>   

}

@if (Model.Navigation != null) 
{
    <div id="layout-navigation" class="group">
        <div id="navigation">
            @Zone(Model.Navigation)
        </div>
    </div>
}


@if (Model.Featured != null) {
<div id="layout-featured" class="group">
    @Zone(Model.Featured)
</div>
}
@if (Model.BeforeMain != null) {
<div id="layout-before-main" class="group">
    @Zone(Model.BeforeMain)
</div>
}

<div id="layout-main-container">
<div id="layout-main" class="group">
    @if (Model.AsideFirst != null) {
    <aside id="aside-first" class="aside-first group">
        @Zone(Model.AsideFirst)
    </aside>
    }
    <div id="layout-content" class="group">
        @if (Model.Messages != null) {
        <div id="messages">
            @Zone(Model.Messages)
        </div>
        }
        @if (Model.BeforeContent != null) {
        <div id="before-content">
            @Zone(Model.BeforeContent)
        </div>
        }
        @* the model content for the page is in the Content zone @ the default position (nothing, zero, zilch) *@
        @if (Model.Content != null) {
        <div id="content" class="group">
            @Zone(Model.Content)
        </div>
        }
        @if (Model.AfterContent != null) {
        <div id="after-content">
            @Zone(Model.AfterContent)
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    @if (Model.AsideSecond != null) {
    <aside id="aside-second" class="aside-second">
        @Zone(Model.AsideSecond)
    </aside>
    }
</div>
</div>

@if (Model.AfterMain != null) {
<div id="layout-after-main" class="group">
    @Zone(Model.AfterMain)
</div>
}
@if (Model.TripelFirst != null || Model.TripelSecond != null || Model.TripelThird != null) {
<div id="layout-tripel-container">
<div id="layout-tripel" class="group">@* as in beer *@
    @if (Model.TripelFirst != null) {
    <div id="tripel-first">
        @Zone(Model.TripelFirst)
    </div>
    }
    @if (Model.TripelSecond != null) {
    <div id="tripel-second">
        @Zone(Model.TripelSecond)
    </div>
    }
    @if (Model.TripelThird != null) {
    <div id="tripel-third">
        @Zone(Model.TripelThird)
    </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
}
@tag.EndElement
<div id="layout-footer" class="group">
    <footer id="footer">
        <div id="footer-quad" class="group">
            @if (Model.FooterQuadFirst != null) {
            <div id="footer-quad-first">
                @Zone(Model.FooterQuadFirst)
            </div>
            }
            @if (Model.FooterQuadSecond != null) {
            <div id="footer-quad-second">
                @Zone(Model.FooterQuadSecond)
            </div>
            }
            @if (Model.FooterQuadThird != null) {
            <div id="footer-quad-third">
                @Zone(Model.FooterQuadThird)
            </div>
            }
            @if (Model.FooterQuadFourth != null) {
            <div id="footer-quad-fourth">
                @Zone(Model.FooterQuadFourth)
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        @if(Model.Footer != null) {
        <div id="footer-sig" class="group">
            @Zone(Model.Footer)
        </div>
        }
    </footer>
</div>
```

**Update**

Derk's solution combined with removing the following Orchard CSS seems to be doing the trick:

```
/* Clearing Floats
***************************************************************/

.group:after 
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}


.zone:after, .widget-control:after /* .zone:after self clears every zone container - .widget-control:after self clears any floats used in a widget */
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Update 2**

Instead of removing the clear floats css `changing content: "."` to `content: ""` seems also to be having the same effect.

A explanation to the cause of this would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Regards,
Zer.

Comment: I don't see the #wrapper that your css refers to, in the html.

Comment: The wrapper is created by the Orchard framework.

Comment: Can you control it? or if not, can you make another one that you will have control over? In your code there is nothing that designates the buffer. You don't have all of the pieces. d

Comment: Hello Derek, I can remove the @tag so the lay-out wrapper gets removed and add my own div wrapper if you mean that.

Comment: Yeah - I mean, there are 4 things you need. A wrapper, some content, a buffer, and a footer. You need to get those somehow. Then style them.

Comment: Orchard is just a CMS. It shoves your content into the divs. There isn't like a way to do it in orchard... There is just the way to do it in HTML and CSS which is what orchard is - except dynamically calling the info to be put in those divs.

Comment: The footer needs to be outside of the wrapper....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For that padding issue**, I would encourage you to check out this border-box method. It moves the padding inside the div instead of outside. So you don't have to calculate padding and div widths etc. in the whole project. It's so helpful!

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Just drop it at the top of your styles! It might take some adjusting to get a site molded back into shape, but It will be worth it.

but for now: add it just to your .zone thing:

```
.zone {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can read more about that here: [Paul Irish talks about border-box](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

**For the footer:**

Check out this pen: [Weighted Footer](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/DiewF)

You already have html and body in your code - but do you have a wrapper of some sort?

If not, you need to put one in:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

    <header></header>

    <section class="main-content"></section>

    <div class="footer-buffer">(BUFFER)</div>

</div> <!-- end .main-wrapper -->

<footer></footer>
```

The very basic structure is here. So check that it, or something similar is in place on your theme.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /* for IE 6 */
  height: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  margin: 0 auto -4em;

  /* new addition */
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer, .footer-buffer {
  height: 4em;
}
```

I would personally put `width: 100%;` and `float: left;` on all of these... But you need to make it as simple as possible to figure out the problem. Then you'll probably want another div like `.inner {max-width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;}` Inside each section to make that standard column website look. I would back up your CSS file and do some more testing like you were doing.

I hope that helps! I had spent so many hours and day fighting that sticky footer!

Comment: Did you figure out the padding issue you were having?

Comment: I had a 2 day freak out on about 10 projects in a row a year or so ago. Each time I figured it out - but It was hell and hacky and I couldn't seem to figure it out again each time. That is why I have spent ton's of time on options and come to the conclusion of the pen I provided. There are a lot of things going on... but if you can narrow things down and get the basic 4 things working, It WILL work. There might be some styles you don't know are there that are messing you up. Try putting your styles at the end of the style sheet for this part. As a test. Simplify as much as you can for now.

Comment: How come its only working with 4em? When i tried changing it to px or a other em it simply is not working? It removed the scrollbar when i use 4em, but its not working when i use for example 2 em. Thanks.

Comment: uh... in my case my reset sets the body font to 62.5% which makes the standard font-size 10px which translates to 1em. so 4em is 40 px, (in my case) - you have to make sure to set whatever number it is (40px or whatever) on both the -margin of the wrapper and the footer and footer buffer. - those 3 things have to be equal.

Comment: Not really sure i am following you there Derek :). My font-size is set on 100%. When i have 4 em (main wrapper footer and buffer) it works when i change the value the scrollbar appears again and everything goes haywire. We are very close but this totally confuses me on why only 1 value is working!

Comment: Yeah. I would just pick a test number. Use 60px. Make sure it's on the margin of the wrapper as `margin: 0 auto -60px;` - and on the footer and footer-buffer as `height: 60px;`

Comment: It seems everything larger then 60px is working but anything lower will introduce the scroll bar and the space under the footer uh.

Comment: Okay i have changed the .zone padding to 8px and tried lowering from 60px to 58px and no scrollbar. Meaning the padding that gets applied to all the zones is again the problem. But i would really like to keep the padding of 10px in the zone, how can i fix this problem? Not really understanding what is causing this conflict. Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried out that border-box property yet? I'm telling you... it's the best. I think - that will fix the problem, by moving the padding inside the box instead of out of the box... So when you say 60px high with 10px padding, it's still 60px high instead of 80px high. See? I would start there to clear that out of the way

Comment: you probably have like and overflow auto or something on there - I can't really picture what the scrollbar issue is. Is this site live?

Comment: Afraid not its still in development phase (and have no provider yet). So weird its only working with 60px or higher. Thanks a lot for the help though, will try to dig in it a little deeper but clueless at the moment.

Comment: I seem to have found the CSS that was causing the issue (Orchard written code that clears floats). But i have no idea why, sort of frustrating. Will update my post on top. Thanks again sheriffderek!