# How to set DIVs so that the page vertically fits the screen?

Tags: html, css, height

This is the structure of a page.

[image]

the height of `header`, `menu` and `footer` is known (fixed and set by pixels) but the `body` height is not. but I want it to be so height such that the site completely covers the screen vertically. I mean I need to set a `min-height` for the `body` that causes the page fits the screen. how can I do that?

Comment: May want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10056827/526741

Comment: So, what happens the content is longer than the page? Does the footer move down? Are you using any javascript in the project, do you have any code in a jsFiddle for us to see?

Comment: @sheriffderek yes it must scroll down. unfortunately my website is based on `Drupal` and there are lot's of server-side code inside it. it is not possible to place it on jsfiddle.

Comment: you can make a small use case, watch... I'll make one in under 2 min...

Comment: @sheriffderek this: http://aalulbaytisp.com/activity/sss

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/YF3Gf/

Comment: This is a CSS question, and I know that drupal and code and everything is hard to separate... but drupal is just some PHP that shoves database crap into html. You may have a complicated theme as a starting point, but it's just CSS - so you should work out the problem in a dedicated space like codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: @sheriffderek it still has my problem !!!

Comment: Do you have to support Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: @Drupalist is this you are looking for? `http://jsbin.com/taralaxi/1/edit`

Comment: Of course it does... it's just some code to start with. Your question is still unclear, and If I give you the full answer, you wont know what to do with it. This is what you probably want. If you you know your footer height... ALWAYS... you wont need the javascript:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE

Comment: @sheriffderek yes I do

Comment: @KheemaPandey if you remove the section content, it won't cover the screen

Comment: @sheriffderek visit this address : aalulbaytisp.com/activity/sss you can see that the `#body` DIV is not so high su ch that it vertically covers the screen

Comment: I see your problem, but it is not a one line fix, you have to understand and adjust a few things across your site.  see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923414/sticky-footer-orchard-cms/14924864#14924864

Comment: @sheriffderek I already found a solution to set the display of the parent to table and its first level DIV to table-row. but it doesn't work now!

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't sound like a solution. I posted an answer. Good luck! When you inevitably run into changing footer sizing in the future, check out the more detailed codepen link. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I should set the display of the site wrapper DIV to `table` and its height to `100%` and every first level DIV display must be `table-row`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways now with flex-box or calc() - but I have a feeling you aren't going to go that route at this time. Here is the best alternative.

The concept is that you have a master container around everything but the footer. You force this to be 100% of the page, but they your footer isn't above the fold. To correct this you can make a negative margin on your master-container, but then that has it's own issues too - and so you add this buffer div that matches the footer height - (and the negative margin of the master-container) This allows the page to fill to the footer, but if the page is longer, gently push the footer down.

Some people will say it's too "hacky," and those people don't seem to stay in this business very long. Of course, your theme is going to have a ton of styles that might conflict with this or mess it up - so watch out for those, and really understand what is happening - so you can adjust for conflicts. It's simple in theory, but anyone who ever built a website has fought this issue. Flex-box offers an incredibly easy solution, but it's hard to implement at the time of this post because of cross-browser compatibility.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/YF3Gf/) with just the most basic code.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE) with a more extensive example

### HTML

```
<div class="container master-container">

    <header class="container global-header">
        header
    </header>

    <nav class="container global-nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="container main-content">
        main-content
    </section>

    <div class="container footer-buffer"><!-- empty --></div>    
</div>

<footer class="container global-footer">
    footer
</footer>
```

### CSS

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* 
Read about it...
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */



html, body {
    height: 100%; /* let them know they can be this tall if they want - because they don't already know for some reason... */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.master-container {
    min-height: 100%; /* force height of html and body */
    margin-bottom: -79px; /* opposite of footer buffer! */
}

.container { /* what is common to all the big blocks */
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.global-header {
    height: 91px;
    background: lightblue;
}

.global-nav .menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.main-content {
    /* ? */
}

.global-footer, .footer-buffer {
    height: 79px; 
}

.global-footer {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following via onload:

```
//You will need to define the header height, footer height and menu height as vars:
function bodyHeight() {
    var headerHeight, footerHeight, menuHeight;
    var scr = screen.availHeight;
    var setBodyHeight = scr - (headerHeight + footerHeight + menuHeight);
    document.body.style.height = setBodyHeight + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it u need ?

updated: http://jsfiddle.net/RQFg3/2/

setting the parent element of body (html) as height 100% and body as well.

CSS

```
* {
padding:0;
border:0;
margin:0;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: These are width 100% by default.

Comment: why would you put no border on everything, when there isn't any, anywhere, to begin with?

Comment: No it doesn't work because if the Body be empty, it won't have any height

Comment: It has height if u set it in css, as in the example.
@sheriffderek just used border to make it "visual"

Comment: @vbotio there is no other way? using pixels has some consequences I want to use pixels

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do it, but here's a quick and dirty example:
http://cdpn.io/uzbdg